# VideoCapture module cannot import name "Device"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, webcam, webcam-capture

I'm trying to write a python script that uses the webcam to observe objects inside of a closed environment on python 3. When I try to run this:

```
from VideoCapture import Device

cam = Device()
cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')
```

It comes up with an error like this:

```
  File "C:/Users/mkamui/Documents/Programming Stuff/Programming Folder/Learning Libraries/Webcam stuff/VideoCapture.py", line 1, in <module>
    from VideoCapture import Device
  File "C:\Users\mkamui\Documents\Programming Stuff\Programming Folder\Learning Libraries\Webcam stuff\VideoCapture.py", line 1, in <module>
    from VideoCapture import Device
ImportError: cannot import name 'Device'
```

I've tried debugging it, but there doesn't seem to be much hope. The class exists within the computer, and I'm pretty sure it is saved in the correct location.

If anyone knows hot to solve this, it will be greatly appreciated.

I've also tried using OpenCV (from 3rd Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages) to control the webcam, but didn't work too well. I've also tried messing around with pygame.camera, but that had no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

i am not much into python but it seems that u may forget to specify the webcam you are using. Maybe its something like cap0 for your webcam. Something like:

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

here the 0 stands for cap0 it takes the camera on your pc at position 0. If you are using multiple webcams it can be that there should be 1 or 2.